# memory leak calling C functions in C#

Tags: c#, c, memory-leaks, interop

I use C dll functions in C#. It works fine except I have a memory leak.

The first C function I use allocates memory (with malloc) and returns an array of string (char***) and the second one frees the memory (using free).

When I test those functions in a C program everything is ok - there are no memory leaks. However when I use those functions in a C# program I have a memory leak.

I 'm sure I'm doing something bad but I can't figure out what.

My code :

```
    [DllImport("TestERP.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int GetArray(string baseval,ref int nb,ref IntPtr array,IntPtr msg);

    [DllImport("TestERP.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int freeMemory( int nb, ref IntPtr array);


public static void GetManagedArray()
    {
         string[] tmp = new string[12];
         int nb = 0;
         IntPtr msg = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(256);
         string tmp2 = "";
         IntPtr intArr = IntPtr.Zero; 

         //call the C function which return the arry of string intArr
         GetArray("val",ref nb,  ref intArr,msg);

         //copy in managed string array
         for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
            tmp[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(intArr, i * IntPtr.Size));

         tmp2 = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(msg);

         Marshal.FreeHGlobal(msg);

         //call the C function whiec free memory
         freeMemory(nb, ref intArr);

         intArr = IntPtr.Zero;

         GC.Collect();

    }
```

I add the code of C functions :

```
int __stdcall GetArray(char base[],int* nb,char*** array,char* outmsg)
{
    int i =0;

    (*array) = (char**)calloc(12, sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        (*array)[i] = calloc(256,sizeof(char));
        sprintf((*array)[i],"%s %d",base,i) ;
    }

    *nb= 12;

    strcpy(outmsg,"message erreur");

   return 0;
}

int __stdcall freeMemory(int nb,char*** array)
{
    int i =0;

    for (i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        free((*array)[i]);
        (*array)[i] = 0;
    }

    free((*array));

    *array = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you have a memory leak?

Comment: I run my function GetArray in a infinite loop and I saw the memory of my exe growing very fast

Comment: Are you able to post your `GetArray` function as well?

Comment: Are you sure you're properly releasing the unmanaged resources? Calling `GC.Collect` wont help you at all here.

Comment: Have you also tried with Marshal.ReleaseObject(object) after performing your operation ?

Comment: I add the code of C functions so you can see I release unmanaged ressources. No memory leak calling those function in C program

Comment: Please change `(*array)[i] = 0;` to `(*array)[i] = NULL;`, that makes it absolutely clear to everyone what is going on in `freeMemory`... that and in your `GetArray` function, you have a recursive `GetArray` call where I think you want a `GetfixedArray` call (the C function is called `GetfixedArray`, the C# function is `GetArray`, from what I see here)

Comment: Sorry I did a bad copy paste, I update the good GetArray function

Comment: I replace (*array)[i] = 0; to (*array)[i] = NULL and it's the same behaviour I also try to add Marshal.Release(object) and I have an exception telling that object cannot be null

Comment: I rename the c# method to GetManagedArray to avoid confusion

Comment: You may well have a memory leak, but it is not from this code.  Just write a little test program that calls GetManagedArray() a million times to prove it to yourself.

Comment: I did it the simple test program and I have a memory leak